# How to calculate the same body height in all browsers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, height, document-body

I am having a problem that I don't know how to solve.

Basically, I am integrating a ScrollToFixed jQuery plugin and for calculating a limit, I use

```
jQuery( document ).height() - jQuery( \'body\').offset().top
```

or

```
jQuery( 'body' ).height()
```

The thing is that it does not work the same in all browsers. I have developed my implementation in Chrome but when I tested it in other browsers, it was a mess.I outputed the value to console and I get 600px difference in height.

Now, since my script will be used on multiple websites by my clients, I must find a universal solution, if it were for me only it would be much easier.

Can you help me out, is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to X-Browser compatibility hell...

Comment: Have you tried [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) instead of `offset().top`?

Comment: why you are calculating height on `body` tag if you want to fix a particular `div` then you should calculate values for that `div` only

Comment: @user113215 yes, no difference

Comment: @Peeyush I need the height of the body because:

limit: bodyHeight - divHeight - desiredStop

bodyHeight - height of a body element
divHeight - height of a div element
desiredStop - user defined stop point for a div

Comment: @user1356223 okay you can try one thing i am not sure that is it the  correct way or not......just wrap your all body content in a `<div id="wrapper">you body content here</div>` and then try to get the height of this newly 'div' rather than the `body`

Comment: I could do that, but as I said, this will be used on multiple websites by multiple clients, I have no way of knowing their html structure, that's the problem.

Comment: Post an example to http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see what you're trying to do and can test.

Comment: Alright, will do, give me 5 minutes

Comment: Outside of jQuery, there's also the native JavaScript method [getBoundingClientRect()](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmcrrn.php) which you could invoke the `<body>` tag with something like `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].getBoundingClientRect()` to get the top and height.

Comment: Ok I have created an example, but the trouble is it works just fine :/

http://jsfiddle.net/T2w9F/1/

I get the same height in all browsers.

Comment: Here is an example where it does not work fine:

http://swar.originalexe.com/sticky-widget-areas-reloaded/

This is my showcase site. Check it out in Chrome first, and then in other browsers.

Comment: Also, on my page, you can see in console the calculation for each panel. 1.) Body height 2.) Div height 3.) Calculated limit etc.

Comment: Your showcase site looks identical in Chrome, Firefox 13, Firefox 19, and IE 9. It appears to be correct (except in all cases, the left red "Unlimited" box collides with the left white "Content restriction?" box).

Comment: It looks the same now because I went with the different logic, I changed the plugin variable from "how much from the bottom should plugin stop" to "how much from the top should plugin stop". This is the worse way as not every page will be of the same height, but nothing else could be done.

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure you [normalize your css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), so it's the same across all browsers.

<del>Then use `$(window).height()` to get the height of the browser window.</del>

---

Update: I had to go look for the `scrollToFixed` plugin since there are multiple similar named ones out there. I [found it here](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed).

If you look at the documentation and the definition of the limit option

> the vertical scroll position at which the element will begin to scroll up the page (absolutely).

So all you need to do is target an element at that position like the author does in the ["Very Full Example" demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/):

```
limit: $('.footer').offset().top - $('#summary').outerHeight(true) - 10;
```

The `.footer` is obviously the footer at the bottom. It gets the offset top, then subtracts out the height of the scrolling window, plus a tiny margin (widen the result frame to see the Summary scrolling window).

Comment: `$(window).height()` gets the height of the viewport (visible portion), but OP wants the height of the document itself.

Comment: @user113215 Thanks, I noticed that after I posted =/... I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, I understand the documentation, the trouble is, as I pointed out, that I don't know the page structure where the plugin will be used, so I can't make references to any objects on page.